# Limit related to $\zeta(x)$

Tags: calculus

I'm noticing some things:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sum_{x=1}^{n} x^{-1/3}-\frac{3}{2}n^{2/3} \right)=\zeta(1/3)$$

Note $\int n^{-1/3} dn=\frac{3}{2}n^{2/3}+c$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sum_{x=1}^{n} x^{-1/2}-\frac{2}{1}n^{1/2} \right)=\zeta(1/2)$$

And

$$\int n^{-1/2}dn=2n^{1/2}+c$$

It seems as though

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sum_{x=1}^{n} x^{-1/s}-\frac{s}{s-1}n^{(s-1)/s} \right)=\zeta(1/s)$$

If $s \neq 1$, may someone please explain why.

Comment: This makes me think of Ramanujan's evaluation $\zeta(1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\int_1^n\frac1xdx\right)$

Comment: @Simple Art ....your result being equal to the Euler constant $\gamma=0.577\cdots$.

Comment: @JeanMarie I mean, its a special value.  But when you Ramanujan sum things like $1^p+2^p+3^p+\dots$, you get the Riemann zeta function (I think).

Comment: @Simple Art I do agree that it is a special value, but sometimes, observing special values indicate some other tracks to follow.

Comment: @JeanMarie Good advice.  :)  But bookmark those special values before leaving the track.

Comment: @user1952009 That is not what I meant.  I was speaking of the Ramanujan evaluation of $\zeta(1)$, not $\zeta(1)$ itself.

Comment: @SimpleArt Yes I know, but you wrote several times $\zeta(1)$ for $\displaystyle\overset{\mathfrak{R}}{\sum} n^{-1} = \gamma$, which is a nonsense so find another notation (in particular $\displaystyle\overset{\mathfrak{R}}{\sum} n^{-s}$ isn't continuous at $s=1$...). And as you probably know, the Ramanujan summation isn't a very common summation method, it is one of the most complicated, and many people use $\displaystyle\overset{\mathfrak{R}}{\sum} a_n = \alpha$ as a short-hand for "with some summation method -try them all-  you should get $\sum a_n = \alpha$"

Comment: See for example https://hal-unice.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01150208/document using $\displaystyle\overset{\mathfrak{R}}{\sum}$ is often a pitty

Comment: @user1952009 yes, I can agree with that, but it's not like I didn't specify here.

Comment: @SimpleArt well I showed you two problems : forget about $\zeta(1) = \gamma$, and try avoiding $\displaystyle\overset{\mathfrak{R}}\sum$ as possible

Answer (score 3):

As $n \to \infty$ : $$n^{-s} -\int_n^{n+1} x^{-s}dx = \int_n^{n+1} (n^{-s}-x^{-s})dx = \int_n^{n+1} \int_n^x s t^{-s-1}dt dx = \mathcal{O}(n^{-s-1})$$

Thus
$$F(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1} x^{-s}dx\right) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}\right)-\int_1^{N+1} x^{-s}dx$$ $$ = \lim_{N \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}\right) - \frac{1-(N+1)^{1-s}}{s-1}$$
converges and is analytic for $Re(s) > 0$.

But for $Re(s) > 1$, $\lim_{N \to \infty} (N+1)^{1-s} = 0$ so that 
$$F(s) = \frac{-1}{s-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} = \frac{-1}{s-1}+\zeta(s)$$
And by [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) this stays true for $Re(s) > 0$ (or if you prefer by the [identity theorem for complex analytic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)).

Finally, since for $Re(s) > 0$  : $\lim_{N \to \infty} (N+1)^{1-s}-N^{1-s} = 0$, you get that for $Re(s) > 0$ : $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}\right) + \frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1} = \lim_{N \to \infty} \left(\sum_{n=1}^N n^{-s}\right) + \frac{(N+1)^{1-s}}{s-1} = F(s)+ \frac{1}{s-1}= \zeta(s)$$

Comment: Oh, nice.  I actually remember seeing this before done in reverse.  Just couldn't remember where I saw it... +1

Comment: May I ponder to ask what happens for $-1<\Re(s)<0$ for $F(s)$?  Seems convergence is possible in that region, but probably doesn't come out to give the Riemann zeta function(?)

Comment: @SimpleArt apply the same trick again : $n^{-s} - \int_n^{n+1} x^{-s}dx - \frac{1}{2}\int_n^{n+1} s x^{-s-1}dx = \mathcal{O}(x^{-s-2})$.

Comment: I mean, how can $F(0)=\zeta(0)+1$?  for example.  If what you say is true, $F(0)$ is the limit point as $s\to0^-$, which should work out since $F$ is analytic, right?

Comment: @SimpleArt $\lim_{s \to 0^+} F(0) = \zeta(0)+1$ yes

Comment: $F(0)=0$ from the original definition of $F$, whereas $\zeta(0)+1=1/2$.

Comment: @SimpleArt well $\lim_{s \to 0^+} F(s) \ne 0$  then

Comment: But if $F$ is analytic, then $\lim_{s\to0^+}F(s)$ should equal $F(0)$?  Huh.  I want to actually see some numerical values for the limit now.

Comment: @SimpleArt yes try. And the expression for $F(s)$ is analytic on $Re(s) > 0$.

Comment: Was thinking that if the representation is analytic on $\Re(s)>0$ but still converges for other values, then it should be analytic there too.  :/  Will do when I get home.

Comment: @SimpleArt For example $h(s) = \sum_{n \ge 1} (-1)^{n+1} n^{-s}$ is analytic on $Re(s) > 1$ whatever the order of summation, but (as we said yesterday) changing the order of summation you can get the value you want for this series at $s= 1$, for example $h(1) = 0$, whereas $\lim_{s \to 1^+} h(s) = \ln 2$

Comment: But that is due to $h(1)$ being conditionally convergent.  Here, $F(s)$ is not conditionally convergent at $s=0$.

Comment: @SimpleArt you don't get it. Let $g(s) = s \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s-1}$. Then $\lim_{s \to 0} g(s) = \lim_{s \to 1} (s-1)\zeta(s) = 1$, while under your reasoning $g(0) = 0$. Here it is exactly the same, since $n^{-s} - \int_n^{n+1} x^{-s}dx= \frac{s}{2} n^{-s-1} + \mathcal{O}(n^{-s-2})$

Comment: @SimpleArt yes a typo $\lim_{s \to 0}$

Comment: Hm, I understand what you're getting at, the sum being a sorts of double limit.  But I still don't feel the same about the $F(0)$ case, it just doesn't... feel the same.

Comment: That representation implies $F(0)$ diverges to infinity btw.

Comment: @SimpleArt I swear it is exactly the same, since I proved on the 1st line that $F(s) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s-1}+ \mathcal{O}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |n^{-s-2}|)$ for $Re(s) > 0$ (well I didn't write it but $\int_n^{n+1} \int_n^x s t^{s-1}dt dx = \int_n^{n+1} \int_n^x s (n^{s-1}+\mathcal{O}(n^{-s-2}))dt dx = s n^{-s-1}+\mathcal{O}(n^{-s-2})$

Comment: @SimpleArt no it doesn't diverge, because $\frac{s}{2} n^{-s-1} \to 0$ as $s \to 0$

Comment: But $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s-1}+\mathcal O(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|n^{-s-2}|)\to\infty$ as $s\to0$.

Comment: @SimpleArt Yes but It is a typo, I meant $F(s) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty s n^{-s-1} + \mathcal{O}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |n^{-s-2}|)$ ... Come on, did you read my answer ?

Comment: Um, but that wasn't in your answer?!  \*facepalm\*

Comment: @SimpleArt so now everything is clear, the $1/2$ that disappeared in $\lim_{s \to 0} F(s) = \zeta(0)+1 = 1/2$ while $F(0) = 0$ is due to the $\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty s n^{-s-1}$ term that is not continuous, with its limit being $1/2$ while its value at $0$ is $0$

Comment: @SimpleArt There is the analytic continuation you always dreamed about 

$\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1} x^{-s}dx =\frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1}\int_n^x s t^{-s-1}dtdx$

$ = \frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{s}{2}\zeta(s+1)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1}\int_n^x s (t^{-s-1}-n^{-s-1})dtdx$
 
$= \frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{s}{2}\zeta(s+1)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1}\int_n^x s \int_n^t (s+1)u^{-s-2}dudtdx$

$ = \frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{s}{2}\zeta(s+1)+\frac{s(s+1)}{2.3}\zeta(s+2)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1}\int_n^x s \int_n^t (s+1)(u^{-s-2}-n^{-s-2})dudtdx$

Comment: $= \frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{s}{2}\zeta(s+1)+\frac{s(s+1)}{2.3}\zeta(s+2)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1}\int_n^x s \int_n^t (s+1)\int_n^u (s+2)v^{-s-3}dvdudtdx$

$ =\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{s}{2}\zeta(s+1)+\frac{s(s+1)}{2.3}\zeta(s+2)+\frac{s(s+1)}{2.3.4}\zeta(s+3)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1}\int_n^x s \int_n^t (s+1)\int_n^u (s+2)(n^{-s-3}-v^{-s-3})dvdudtdx$

Comment: Lol, I get it.  Interesting expansion.  By the way, you can use `\.` to create spaces between all the d#'s.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{\sum_{x = 1}^{n}x^{-1/3} - {3 \over 2}\,n^{2/3}} =
> \zeta\pars{1 \over 3}}$

\begin{align}
\sum_{x = 1}^{n}x^{-1/3} & =
{3 \over 2}\sum_{x = 1}^{n}{x - 1/3 \over x^{1/3}} -
{3 \over 2}\sum_{x = 1}^{n}x^{2/3}
+ {3 \over 2}\sum_{x = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over \pars{x + 1}^{1/3}}
\\[5mm] & =
{3 \over 2}\sum_{x = 1}^{n}{x - 1/3 \over x^{1/3}} -
{3 \over 2}\sum_{x = 1}^{n}x^{2/3}
+ {3 \over 2} + {3 \over 2}\sum_{x = 1}^{n}{1 \over \pars{x + 1}^{1/3}} -
{3 \over 2}{1 \over \pars{n + 1}^{1/3}}
\\[1cm] & =
-\,{3 \over 2}\sum_{x = 1}^{n}
\bracks{{x \over \pars{x + 1}^{1/3}} - {x - 1/3 \over x^{1/3}}} + {3 \over 2} +
{3 \over 2}\ \underbrace{%
\bracks{\sum_{x = 1}^{n}\pars{x + 1}^{2/3} - \sum_{x = 1}^{n}x^{2/3}}}
_{\ds{-1 + \pars{n + 1}^{2/3}}}
\\ & \phantom{=\,\,}-\,{3 \over 2}{1 \over \pars{n + 1}^{1/3}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\mbox{Then,}\quad\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{%
\sum_{x = 1}^{n}x^{-1/3} - {3 \over 2}\,n^{2/3}}\ =\
\overbrace{-\,{3 \over 2}
\sum_{x = 1}^{\infty}
\bracks{{x \over \pars{x + 1}^{1/3}} - {x - 1/3 \over x^{1/3}}}}
^{\ds{=\ \zeta\pars{1 \over 3}}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] & \phantom{=}+\
\underbrace{{3 \over 2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\pars{n + 1}^{2/3} -
\,{3 \over 2}{1 \over \pars{n + 1}^{1/3}} - n^{2/3}}}_{\ds{=\ 0}}\ =\
\bbox[10px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\zeta\pars{1 \over 3}}}
\end{align}

> The series, in the \eqref{1} RHS, is a [$\ds{\zeta}$-representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Dirichlet_series) which is obtained by a rearrange of the 'original definition' such that it extends the series validity range. Details are given in the above cited link.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Wikipedia of Ramanujan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation#Sum_of_divergent_series) (a few paragraphs down):

> It has been proposed to use of $C(1)$ rather than $C(0)$ as the result of Ramanujan's summation, since then it can be assured that one series 
>   $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }f(k)$ admits one and only one Ramanujan's summation, defined as the value in $1$ of the only solution of the difference equation 
>   $R(x)-R(x+1)=f(x)$ that verifies the condition $\int_{1}^{2}R(t)dt=0$. This definition of Ramanujan's summation (denoted as $\sum _{n\geq 1}^{\Re }f(n)$) does not coincide with the earlier defined Ramanujan's summation, $C(0)$, nor with the summation of convergent series, but it has interesting properties, such as: If $R(x)$ tends to a finite limit when $x\to1^+$, then the series 
>   $\sum _{n\geq 1}^{\Re }f(n)$ is convergent, and we have
>
> $$\sum_{n\ge1}^\Re f(n)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^Nf(n)-\int_1^Nf(t)dt\right)$$

which seems to be exactly what you are looking for.  More context is provided in the link.

Comment: How does one calculate such a sum?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Tad more specific please?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla I honestly don't know.  I'm not very familiar with this method of summing divergent series.  My naïve approach would be connecting zeta regularization to $\sum_{n\ge1}^\Re n^s$ somehow.