# Ramanujan sum. What is it, and how do we calculate it?

Tags: summation, ramanujan-summation

Can someone please explain the concept of a Ramanujan sum in easier language than Wikipedia and its relation to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961275/limit-related-to-zetax). Then, how to calculate the Ramanujan sum:

$$\sum _{n\geq 1}^{\Re } n^{-1/s}$$

To show it equal to:

$$\zeta(1/s)$$

Comment: what is your definition of the Ramanujan sum ? As Alex.R said in the comment, we need to show that $f(z)  =\displaystyle\overset{\mathcal{R}}\sum_{n \ge 1} n^{-z}$ is analytic in $z$

Answer (score 0):

$$\zeta(z):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^z}.$$

Plug in $z=1/s$.

Comment: Doesn't that only hold for $re(z)>1$?

Comment: Well then it needs to be defined for $z\leq 1$ by analytic continuation.

Comment: Do you know what does this have to do with the question in the link?