# How to find limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $\displaystyle a_{n} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}i^{-1/3} $ and $b_{n} = n^{2/3}$.

No we want to find $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n}-\frac{3}{2}b_{n}$?

Actually I find it lower bound , but I used Abel summation, have no idea how to find it easier.

Comment: Apply the integral test for bounds.

Comment: @SimpleArt I want to know the easiest solution.

Comment: @SimpleArt I understand that I could use integral test, but I guess it's possible to simplify the sequence.

Comment: I'm betting it converges to $\zeta(1/3)$.

Comment: @SimpleArt I get the same result , but that was a bit difficult.

Comment: I forgot where I saw it, but the limit of the sum minus the integral of this form converges to the zeta function

Comment: I think this has an answer: [Limit related to $\zeta(x)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961275/limit-related-to-zetax)